# why Page break is not working when the SSRS report is migrated from one server to another server.?

Tags: reporting-services, reportmanager

I have a main report which is having multiple subreports. Each subreports are supposed to occur in a seperate Page when exported to excel or PDF. This is working fine in the Production. But recently we have migrated the same RDL from production a New server. Nothing got changed exceptfor Data source connection. But surprising issue is, the report which is working fine in Production is not behaving as its supposed to. The subreports are not occuring in different page. Infact 2 subreports are occuring in single page and the other two in the next page. Dont know what got changed and why the page break is not working here. Can Anyone help me with this?

Comment: Have you ruled out the idea that a design flaw in the report may have just been noticed in the new environment? I would replicate the data in the old environment to ensure that the problem didn't exist before the move. Data sources shouldn't affect report rendering, however data can easily change report appearances

Comment: thanks for replying Chance! Consider the simple RDL when connected to Production it is breaking the page to 4 but when connected to test server its not. I believe even if the data is not same page break should work as it is given. We are not applying any logical per page. Its just a simple page break per subreport.

Comment: simple RDL's can still have problems, see this SO question for a great example. I would eliminate as many variables as you can. The RDL didn't change, but the underlying data did. Page Breaks are based off of data in the report

Comment: hey chance. As you said it was the data issue itself. thanks a lot. The problem is solved. One of the table was truncated in my server where as it was not in the other servers which determined the order of page break.

Comment: Sure thing. Glad i could help